# UTF-8 is not working for converting byte[] to string

Tags: c#, utf-8, hbase

I have a qualifier(long value type) in row of H-Base table.

I want to fetch H-Base rows in between of two long numbers. For that I am using following filters.

My filters are like :

```
long startEpochInDay = 384;

long endEpochInDays = 396;

string startDayFilter = "SingleColumnValueFilter('" + cf + "','" + qualifier + "', >= ,'binary:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(startEpochInDays)) + "',true,true)";

string endDayFilter = "SingleColumnValueFilter('" + cf + "','" + qualifier + "', < ,'binary:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(endEpochInDays)) + "',true,true)";

string finalFilter = startDayFilter + " AND " + endDayFilter
```

These filters are working fine with number less than **383**, but fails if number is greater than this number.

I found while debugging while converting long number to Byte array it returns byte array like ***\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\128***.

When last number in byte array is 127 or less, **UTF-8** works fine but as this number becomes 128 or greater than that, **UTF-8** started returning **"?"** for last digit.

If I use following method to encoding byte array to string

```
Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true,true);
string number = encoding.GetString(HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(startEpochInDays));
```

**UTF-8** is throwing exception while converting byte array(if last digit is 128 or more in byte array) to string in filter.

**Exception** - Unable to translate bytes [8B] at index 6 from specified code page to Unicode.

Inner Exception -

```
at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes)
at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32 count, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding)
at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
at System.Text.Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ....you are converting an int to byte representation, and then somehow expect those bytes to form valid UTF-8 characters? Huh? There are far more logical ways to convert int to string... like, `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UTF8 is not an appropriate way of encoding arbitrary bytes as a string. Rather: it encodes arbitrary strings as bytes (and vice-versa, as long as the bytes are in the correct format). There is no reason to think that `HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(startEpochInDays)` returns UTF-8 data, so `encoding.GetString` is entirely inappropriate and is actually using the `Encoding` *backwards*. This is the [first topic I discussed here](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) - so don't panic: you're in good company - people make this mistake ***all the time***.

What you should be using is something like base-16 (hexadecimal) or base-64.

To get hex: `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])`. To get base-64: `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`

If you need the data to be in a particular format that isn't base-64 or base-16, then you'll have to be specific about what format you want. But: it isn't "UTF-8 used backwards".

Comment: Just a question: 1) if they are arbitrary bytes--how would you figure this and conclude they are arbitrary? 2) if they are arbitrary then how will you make sense of it? I mean there is no mapping for it--am I missing something?

Comment: @CodingYoshi 1: a) because it doesn't work, hence this question, and b) from the name `HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(startEpochInDays)` - that *really* doesn't sound like it is returning UTF-8 - it sounds like it is returning an 8 byte big-endian representation of a 64-bit number  (partly using the example text in the question to infer 64-bit)); 2) I'd need to know what the *expected* format is; I'm not especially familiar with H-Base, but I know my way around binary and UTF-8 pretty well.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your valuable explanation. I tried both ways as you suggested. But no luck. I saved that value as following command - BitConverter.GetBytes(HBaseGenericHelper.SwapEndianness(epochInDays))

Comment: @amit_chauhan ultimately, you're going to have to find out what H-Base expects here. Is there some documentation? Do you even need to use binary data here? Would it not work with `startEpochInDays` concatenated formatted as a regular integer?

Comment: @MarcGravell value is stored in hbase like **\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01~**. I didn't find any specific documentation. How would H-Base compares an integer value as it compares in binary format I guess? I am saving value in H-Base like -- `BitConverter.GetBytes(HBaseGenericHelper.SwapEndianness(epochInDays))`

Comment: @amit_chauhan how it is stored is actually not the issue; the issue is: *what does the DSL expect*; now, if the DSL expects the thing you've just posted as text, then fine: we can do that. `string.Concat(HBaseGenericHelper.GetBigEndianByteArray(startEpochInDays).Select(x => @"\x" + x.ToString("x2")))` should do that

Comment: @MarcGravell It's started giving correct string, but still not able to fetch the results. Data is there in H-Base database. This might be issue with H-Base's **Binary comparison**. I will try to figure out. Thanks for response.